# Improving code for scraping data from a table in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Using `BeautifulSoup` I managed to get data from webpages where everything has labels, but without them I am doing a poor job.

I'm trying to get the dollar exchange rate from:
http://www.bancochile.cl/cgi-bin/cgi_mone?pagina=inversiones/mon_tasa/cgi_mone

The value is highlighted after in yellow below:

[image]

After a lot of trial and error, I manage to get the dollar exchange rate, but I think there has to be a better way.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.bancochile.cl/cgi-bin/cgi_mone?pagina=inversiones/mon_tasa/cgi_mone")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all("table")
dollar = tables[4].find_all("td")

print(dollar[5].string)
```

Is there a better, or more correct way to do this?

Also, I'm not sure if the problem is in the way I coded, or in not being able to better understand the html structure, to navigate to the information in a more efficient way.

Comment: If you're not actually running into any problems but just want to improve your code i think this question might be better off on codereview.stackexchange.com rather then on SO

Comment: Given that the site developers have seen fit to not put any useful classes/IDs on anything, that might be as good as you can get. It's fragile, though; it will break if they rearrange the page.

Comment: @Shogunivar Thank you for the advice. I'm new in Stackoverflow, and I wasn't aware of Stackexchange. I posted this same question there, and got a better way of scraping the data. In case is useful for someone, here is the link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159383/scraping-data-from-a-table-in-python

Comment: @Pablo No problem man, Glad to see you found your answers